# Splitting a double into an array Java

Tags: java, arrays, double

I am writing a program that changes doubles into arrays. So if i had this:

`double d = 1.23456`

I woud want an array like this:

```
array[0] = 1
array[1] = 2
array[2] = 3
```

and so on.

Another example:

```
double d = 3.1415926
```

to

```
array[0] = 3
array[1] = 1
array[5] = 9
```

Some of you wanted to see my code, so here it is:

```
long l = (new Double(3.1415926)).longValue();
String s = Long.toString(l);
System.out.println(l); //prints 3, so splitting won't have any effect
System.out.println(s); //prints 3, so splitting won't have any effect
```

Comment: show us your attempt.

Comment: I want world peace. Please show us your attempt.

Comment: Second example seems correct.

Comment: I've tried several times, latest has been converting to long and then to string, finally splitting. But that just returns 3

Comment: Have you already covered simple casting in your course?

Comment: @MrKireko *show us* your attempt

Comment: @PM77-1 no, i haven't done that yet.

Comment: then get ready for this question to be closed.

Comment: How many digits you need to show?

Comment: @tieTYT What do you mean? Showing you the code of my latest attempt?

Comment: Yes, show us your code.

Comment: They are trying to help you understand how to do this problem but it sounds like a homework assignment that you want the answer to.  By posting your failed attempt, we can see that you are trying and then we can show you where you went wrong.

Comment: The requirement is fuzzy. Is the double always going to have only 1 digit before the decimal? Also(assuming no to the first question) should, "123.4" map to the same array as "1.234"?

Comment: MrKireko - `long`-type variables can't have decimal places (they store only whole numbers -- integers), that's why you lose all the numbers after the dot.  You need to think of some other solution.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the simplest solution is to create a string from double:

```
String s = Double.toString(d);
```

and then parse it skipping decimal dot, and fill your array.

Comment: It should have been a comment,instead of an answer to the question.

Comment: @Algorithmist It *is* an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Please Try this

```
 public static void main(String[] args) 

    {
        Double d = 1.2546;

        String s = d.toString();
        int a[] = new int[s.length()];
        for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
        {
            if(s.charAt(i)!='.')
            {
                a[i]=Integer.parseInt(s.charAt(i)+"");
                System.out.println(a[i]);
            }
        }

    }
```

ouput

```
1
2
5
4
6
```

Answer (score 0):

```
double d = 1.23456;

ArrayList<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
while (d != 0) {
    arrayList.add((int) d);
    d = (d - ((int) d)) * 10.0;
}
System.out.println(arrayList.toString());
```

Probably not the best solution, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
double d = 3.14159;
String s = String.valueOf(d); // convert the double to a string
s = s.replace(".", ""); // delete all dots from the string
int[] ints = new int[s.length()]; // create an array to hold each digit
for (int i = 0; i < ints.length; i++) { // foreach character in the string
     // convert the next character in the string to an int and save it to array
    ints[i] = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(i, i + 1));
}
// print the array
for (int i : ints) System.out.println(i);
```